# Extract words after a symbol in python

Tags: python, regex

I have the following data where i would like to extract out source= from the values. Is there a way to create a general regex function so that i can apply on other columns as well to extract words after equal sign?

```
Data                      Data2
source=book               social-media=facebook
source=book               social-media=instagram 
source=journal            social-media=facebook
```

Im using python and i have tried the following:

```
df['Data'].astype(str).str.replace(r'[a-zA-Z]\=', '', regex=True)
```

but it didnt work

Comment: `df['Data'].str.split('=').str[-1]` couldn't you do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this :

```
df.replace(r'[a-zA-Z]+-?[a-zA-Z]+=', '', regex=True)
```

It gives you the following result :

```
      Data      Data2
0     book   facebook
1     book  instagram
2  journal   facebook
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not required in this situation:

```
print(df['Data'].apply(lambda x : x.split('=')[-1]))
print(df['Data2'].apply(lambda x : x.split('=')[-1]))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to repeat the character class 1 or more times and you don't have to escape the equals sign.

What you can do is make the match a bit broader matching all characters except a whitespace char or an equals sign.

Then set the result to the new value.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [
    "source=book",
    "source=journal",
    "social-media=facebook",
    "social-media=instagram"
]

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=["Data"])
df['Data'] = df['Data'].astype(str).str.replace(r'[^\s=]+=', '', regex=True)
print(df)
```

Output

```
        Data
0       book
1    journal
2   facebook
3  instagram
```

If there has to be a value after the equals sign, you can also use str.extract

```
df['Data'] = df['Data'].astype(str).str.extract(r'[^\s=]+=([^\s=]+)')
```